# Erro de acentuação no json com php

Tags: php, json

Boa tarde pessoal, podem me ajudar?
Tenho um código parecido com isso:

```
$var = "Paraná";
echo $var;
$json = json_encode($var);
echo $json;
```

No echo do $var, me retorna: Paraná. No echo do $json me retorna: Paran\u00e1.

O mesmo problema ocorre para qualquer outro caracter "especial" (à õ í é ü ç etc).

Já tentei: ---- header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ---- utf8_encode($json); ---- utf8_decode($json); ---- < meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>;

Nada corrige.
Alguém conhece uma solução?
Obrigado!!

Comment: Isso se chama escape, se esta usando json_encode em string então é porque tem a pretenção de passar para um json ela, ou não? Sendo assim não é problema de codec, não tem problema algum, a aplicação que for usar o JSON de resposta irá ajustar sozinho, por exemplo se for uma resposta Ajax.... agora se esta usando json_encode e não pretende trabalhar com JSON então isto que você fez no código não tem sentido.

Comment: Entendo. Então é erro meu mesmo. Obrigado pela informação! Só gostaria de marcar a sua resposta como a melhor, mas, como comentário não habilita.

Comment: {"a":"\u00e1"}e {"a":"á"}são maneiras diferentes de escrever o mesmo documento JSON. O decodificador JSON decodificará o escape unicode. A partir do php 5.4+ você pode utilizar: ```$json = json_encode($var, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);``` que irá imprimir certo.